# In arcwise connected and completely normal space, two mutually separated sets can be enclosed by two disjoint neighbourhoods

Tags: general-topology

How do I prove or disprove above claim ?
These are the definitions of Completely normal space, arcwise connected space and mutually separated sets.

> [Normal and Completely Normal spaces](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space)
>
> [Arcwise Connected space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arcwise-Connected.html)
>
> **Mutually Separated**: Two sets A and B of M are said to be mutually separated if they are disjoint and open in their union.

Comment: Are the negative numbers and the non-negative numbers mutually separated?

Comment: No. Their union is R. They are certainly disjoint in R with usual topology but not open.

Comment: But you wrote: “... we’re open in their union.”  What precisely means “mutually separate”?

Comment: If you take two sets A and B from parent space M such that they are disjoint, if they are open in union of A and B as subspace topology then they are mutually separated.

Comment: In your example, union of A and B is R(space of real numbers). A and B are disjoint but set of non negative real numbers is not open since 0 is not interior point of B in R

Comment: Being mutually open is just being completely separated: if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A$ is open in $A \cup B$, then there is an $O_A$ open in $X$ such that $A = O_A \cap (A \cup B)$. But then no point of $A$ is in $\overline{B}$ (in $X$) as witnessed by $O_A$. The same for $B$ being open in the union and $B \cap \overline{A} = \emptyset$. The reverse is also true: if $A$ and $B$ are completely separated, they are disjoint and $(A \cup B) \cap \overline{A} = A$, showing that $A$ is closed in $A \cup B$, so $B$ is open in $A \cup B$ and symmetrically for $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *definition* of being completely normal is that two completely separated subsets of $X$ can be separated by disjoint neighbourhoods, where your stated definition that $A$ and $B$ are mutually separated iff they are open and disjoint in their union is equivalent to the more standard one that $A$ and $B$ are totally separated, I.e. $A \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset = \overline{A} \cap B$ (that Wikipedia also uses). A small moment's thought will convince you of this.

So the arcwise connected bit is a red herring (i.e. totally unrelated), and I suppose this must be a detail in a larger proof that you were stuck on (?), but I'm afraid it's just a restatement of a definition..

Comment: Arcwise connectedness cannot be dispensed since you have examples where above claim becomes false without arcwise connectedness. Take trivial topology on two element set.

Comment: Moreover I have taken sets to be "mutually separated" which is different from "completely separated".

Comment: @user579315 the trivial topology is completely normal and satisfies your statement.

Comment: For A and B when mutually separated, they are completely separated in their union, but why would they be completely separated in parent space. For instance, limit point of A may be in B with respect to parent space but not in the subspace AUB

Comment: @user579315 if $A$ and $B$ are mutually separated then there is an open set $O$ such that $O \cap (A \cup B)=A$ and this implies that no point of $A$ is a limit point of B$, so $A\cap \overline{B}=\emptyset$. Etc.

Comment: That's right. I missed this. Thank you.

Comment: @user579315 You're welcome, I think it's good to realise this equivalence.